# Terminating NSTimer when navigating away from one view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, nstimer

I just happened to realize that `NSTimer` is still firing when i'm navigating away from a `ViewController` like pressing back button. What is the appropriate way to terminate that particular `NSTimer`?

Comment: Can you post your code, wt u tried. that will help to answer appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle it in the viewDidDisappear event:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [myTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: this method will mess up for modelaviewcontroller on pushing navigationcontroller.

Comment: @AlexMarkman: I am just interested: Can you explain where the problem with this method is?

Comment: the -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated method will be called on certain cases. I m listing possible cases:

- When you present a modelviewcontroller
- When you push any controller
- If app goes in the background. that's why this method is not a good practice while you are performing certain actions on perticular events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for terminate your `NSTimer`-

```
[timer invalidate]; //timer is your NSTimer
```

You can `invalidate` your `timer` like this -

**1. Method**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

**2. Method**

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: ya..but at what point after navigating from that view controller?I tried placing it at dealloc and viewdidunload but yield no effect.

Comment: You can write it in `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method. This method would be call just before the disappearance of current `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your question:

**That You want to invalidate timer while going to another ViewController right?**

So try this:

```
YourViewController *objController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objController animated:YES];
[timer invalidate]; //your timer object goes here
```

**EDIT:**

or if you are Popping Up the ViewConrtoller/ Dismissing viewContoller, then put

```
[timer invalidate];
```

afer that block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make custom navigationcontroller class using which you can have an event while poping viewcontroller.

```
#import "customNavigationController.h"
#import "SettingsTableController.h"

@implementation customNavigationController

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] class] == [SettingsTableController class]){
        [[(SettingsTableController *)[self.viewControllers lastObject] timer] invalidate];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.00];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                    forView:self.view cache:NO];

        UIViewController *viewController = [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        return viewController;
    } else {
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
}
@end
```

here, SettingsTableController is the class which is having NSTimer , so u can invalidate your timer. This will help not to invalidate timer while presenting any modalview or even pushing a  view controller.

more details http://www.hanspinckaers.com/custom-action-on-back-button-uinavigationcontroller